# DBIx::Class virtual column?

Tags: perl, catalyst, dbix-class

I am building an app with a DBIx::Class (Loader) based ORM. Most of my database models have a 'name' column. One of my controllers searches all schema classes using primarily the 'name' column. A couple of schema classes however don't have a 'name' column.

Is it possible in DBIx::Class to add a sort of 'virtual' column that uses another column instead:

```
$resultset('Account')->search({name => 'foobar'})
```

secretly rewrites to

```
$resultset('Account')->search({accountnumber => 'foobar'})
```

I hope I am making sense, anyone?

Thx, 
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible - not as a key in a search query anyhow. What you could do is create a base-class for all your resultset classes (you are using [load_namespaces](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aSchema#load_namespaces), right?) which has a method `find_by_name` or similar, that performs this search on the correct column. The column could default to **name** but be overridden by a class attribute - which you can set up with [mk_accessor](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Class%3a%3aData%3a%3aInheritable#mk_classdata).

You can set this base-class to be the default resultset class for all your resultsets with the `default_resultset_class` attribute of [load_namespaces](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aSchema#load_namespaces)